# how to fix unknown directive error in nginx?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm currently getting the following error with nginx:

```
$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "sd#" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:27
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

As a result none of my reverse proxies work anymore. Anyone an idea what's causing this and how I can fix it?

For the record: I made a small change in the config (copy pasted code some code in), but reverted back again after I got the error. At the time my reverse proxies where still functioning, but after a server reboot they all stopped functioning (which makes sense). Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, stupidly misread the error output. Apparently I duplicated the default file into default.save. There also was a typo in the duplicated config, which was the "#sd". Removed default.save and everything works again :)

Comment: Usually, looking at the named file and line, and comparing with relevant examples from the documentation, will give you a good place to start figuring out what's wrong.